# How to edit testcases in TFS

Tags: testing, tfs, testcase

I want to add a column in test case in "steps" field.
Now there are 3 columns "Action", "Expected result", "Attachments", I want to add one more column "Actual result" that will display in every test run iteration.
Is there any way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `Steps field` in test case uses `TestStepsControl` control. It does not support expansion and customization.

So there is no such method to add new column to the Test Steps.

Here is [a ticket](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/21e739b4-4901-40af-9452-95d1442fd16a/how-to-add-more-columns-to-teststeps-in-test-case-wit?forum=tfsprocess) about the similar requirement.

I can fully understand your requirements. You could submit a suggestion ticket about this feature in [our UserVoice website](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html).

[image]